# Criar controles dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte jquery

```
function MontaTraslado() {

    resultado = jQuery.parseJSON('{"txtDestino": "' + $("#txtGeoTo").val() + '" , "datIda": "' + $("#txtDateStart").val() +
                                '", "datVolta": "' + $("#txtDateEnd").val() + '", "intAdultos": "' + $("#txtAdulto").val() +
                                '", "intCriancas": "' + $("#txtCrianca").val() + '", "quaAdulto": "' + $("#txtQuaAdulto").val() +
                                '", "quaCrianca": "' + $("#txtQuaCrianca").val() + '", "quaMaisCinco": "' + $("#txtQuaMaisCinco").val() +
                                '", "idGeoAreDestino": "' + $("#idGeoAreDestino").val() + '" }');

    var str = "";

    $.ajax({

        url: "/Servico/MontaTraslado",
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _servico: resultado }),
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.searchResult != "") {

                $(data.searchResult).each(function () {

                    //str += '<div class="detalhes-servicos-adicionais">';
                    str += '<div class="itens">';
                    str += '<div class="grid_1 checkbox">';


                    str += '<input type="checkbox" value="1" />';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '<div class="grid_12">';
                    str += '<p>';

                    str += this.ProductName + '<br />';
                    //str += 'Aeroporto - Hotel<br />';
                    //str += 'Hotel Aeroporto';

                    str += '</p>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '<div class="grid_4">';
                    str += '<div class="valor">+ R$ 0,00</div>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';


                    str += '<div class="grid_18">';
                    str += '<button value="novaPesquisa" class="btn-pular-passo pull-right">Continuar</button>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    //str += '</div>';

                    $('#translados').html(str);

                    str = "";

                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('#translados').html("<center><h1>Nenhum registro encontrado.</h1></center>");
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {

            loading(0, "LoadbuscaServico");
        }
    });
```

No atual contexto meu, o each dessa função se repete 19 vezes, ou seja, possuo 19 registros nessa situação. Eu preciso ir criando checkboxes e ir adicionando a ele um texto que eu trago de this.ProductName. Acontece se eu deixar como está, ele irá sobreescrevendo o atual description e no final terei apenas um checkbox com o último description, ou seja, somente o último registro. Se eu fizer um for, ele se repetirá 19 vezes na primeira passada(correto e é o que eu quero) e mais 19 vezes em cada outra iteração do each do jquery(isso não quero). A pergunta é: Como eu faço para ter os 19 checkboxes que eu preciso dinamicamente na minha página? Acho que é aqui que eu deveria fazer meu for:

```
str += '<input type="checkbox" value="1" />';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '<div class="grid_12">';
                    str += '<p>';

                    str += this.ProductName + '<br />';
                    //str += 'Aeroporto - Hotel<br />';
                    //str += 'Hotel Aeroporto';

                    str += '</p>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '<div class="grid_4">';
                    str += '<div class="valor">+ R$ 0,00</div>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem o  `$('#translados').html(str);` dentro do for each, isso vai fazer com que o conteúdo seja re-escrito a cada vez que o for faz um loop. Você devia usar o [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) (que acrescenta ao html que já existe), ou usar o .html() fora do loop.

Dê uma olhada a [**este exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6aEs/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('#translados').html('Usando .html(): ' + i);                 // esta linha sobrepôe os valores
    $('#translados2').append('Usando .append(): ' + i + '<br />'); // esta linha mantem o que já havia e acrescenta
}
```

portanto se quiser usar o `.html()` coloque depois do fecho da função `.each()` e antes do fecho do `if`:

```
    });
    $('#translados').html(str);
}
else
```